# Firebase write to database impossible with no error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, setvalue

I want to write to relational database in firebase. My code is like this:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.1"
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation project(':andengine:AndEngine-GLES2-AnchorCenter')
}
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and the project level `build.gradle` code

```
allprojects {
   repositories {
       google()
       jcenter()
       maven {
          url "https://maven.google.com"
       }
   }
}
```

and the android code is :

```
private FirebaseDatabase database;
private DatabaseReference users;
.....
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
users = database.getReference("user");
users.child("username").setValue("ali");
```

everything goes right but there is no change in firebase data. Is it related to manifest or version of firebase gradle or avd?

The database connects well and OK.

Comment: Do you have internet permission?

Comment: where can i find the logs? or any event handler like onComplete or onFailure not trigerred

Comment: Did you sign in before writing to the database? If you would like to bypass the sign-in, you need to change the security rules in the database to allow public read and write

Comment: I have the internet permission in manifest also

Comment: I have changed he rules to true and true. yes bu no working

Answer (score 0):

Change your rules to:

```
{
"rules": {
  ".read": true,
  ".write": true
 }
}
```

Comment: [object Object]   mine is also like this. but no change on database

Comment: you are using a very old version, you should update the firebase-database

Comment: Finally solved and it was for quotes around "true" i eliminated in rules the solved. Thanks to all

Comment: sorry for all , but without any modification again data are not saved and event onSuccess and onFailure not trigerred.  what is the reason.